# Excel Column Converter with a specific Column Does not works

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I tried to code the program that allows the user enter the column and sort the column and replace the cell to the other entered information but I probably get syntact errors

```
I tried to search but I could not find any solution

import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('List')

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O'])


findL = ['example']
replaceL = ['convert']


col = 'C';

df[col] = df[col].replace(findL, replaceL)
```

> TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=float64)' and 'str'

Comment: You could add a short snap of your datframe you are using)

Answer (score 0):

I seems that your `df[col]` and `findL`and `replaceL`do not have the same datatype. Try to run `df[col] = df[col].astype(str)` beofre you run `df[col]=df[col].replace(findL, replaceL)`and it should work

Comment: I get Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 9, saw 2 error ,what is that mean

Answer (score 0):

If the column/s you are dealing with has blank entries in it, you have to specify the `na_filter` parameter in `.read_csv()` method to be `False`.

That way, it will take all the column entries with blank/empty values as str and thus the not empty ones as str as well.

Doing the `.replace()` method using this will not give a TypeError as you will be parsing through both columns as `strings` and not `'ndarray(dtype=float64)` and `str`.